# What is the use of ,/^}/ when searching through Git using regular expression?

Tags: regex, git

I'm currently learning Git by following the book "progit 2nd edition".

In the section discussing "git log -L", the author mentioned

[image]

I understand the string between `'/ /'` is treated as regular expression, but I was wondering what `,/^}/` is there for?

I had a query `git log -L '/myMethodName/':MyJavaFileName` and everything worked as expected. So why did the author included `,/^}/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/pattern1/,/pattern2/` defines a range of lines between two patterns.

`/^}/` only means a line that starts with a `}`